# Designer process terminated in Custom Control with Binding Content

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have created a custom User Control from a Gruopbox. However, in order to be used as a container in a view, I must create a `DependecyProperty` for the `Content`. This results in an `Unhandled Exception has occurred` error in VS2017.

[image: Picture of the error]

This however, only happens when I bind the `Content` attribute in the gruopbox to my new Property.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Infrastructure.Controls.GroupBox.CollectionBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="Form"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <GroupBox Content="{Binding Content, ElementName=Form}"/>

</UserControl>
```

With the code behind being

```
public new object Content
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }
public new static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Content), typeof(object), typeof(CollectionBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

I tried using `FalloutValue` in the Binding to other controls as I assumed the designer didn't know what to put inside the container. Nevertheless, the error keeps occurring.

In runtime and in the view Designer the control looks and works fine. It is just in its designer that I can not see it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a `GroupBox` instead of a `UserControl` that contains a `GroupBox`? Change the root element in your XAML and the base class of the code-behind class from `UserControl` to `GroupBox`.

Comment: @mm8 The exemple is a simplification of the control, as I have found that the error happens due to that Binding. By this I mean that the `GroupBox` is inside another container with other controls.

Comment: What if you create a custom template for the `UserControl`?

Comment: And how would that solve the content binding?

Comment: You don't need to bind. You simply include a `<ContentPresenter />` in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another Content property, just another ControlTemplate, that defines the visual structure of your control, including the GroupBox that binds to the control's `Content`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Infrastructure.Controls.GroupBox.CollectionBox" ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="UserControl">
            <Border> <!-- or any other control(s) here -->
                <GroupBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks